# How to ignore js files on a specific subfolder?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have the following structure

[image: structure]

I want to tell `.gitignore` to ignore `js`, `map` file types.

I tried the following

```
# =========================
# Web essentials auto-generated files
# =========================
TypeScript.Content/Scripts/*.js
TypeScript.Content/Scripts/*.js.map
```

But when I change the js file (or 'create' it) it adds to the list of pending changes...

Is something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that the `.js` and `.map` files that you wish git to ignore are already present in the index.  You need to tell git to un-track those files:

```
git rm --cached TypeScriptTest.Content/Scripts/*.js
git rm --cached TypeScriptTest.Content/Scripts/*.js.map
```

Quote from GitHub help on [Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files):

> Note that git will not ignore a file that was already tracked before a
>   rule was added to this file to ignore it.